# Necessary to use expect.assertions() if you're awaiting any async function calls?

Tags: jestjs

I've found a lot of this sort of thing when refactoring our Jest test suites:

```
it('calls the API and throws an error', async () => {
  expect.assertions(2);
  try {
    await login('email', 'password');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.name).toEqual('Unauthorized');
    expect(error.status).toEqual(401);
  }
});
```

I believe the `expect.assertions(2)` line is redundant here, and can safely be removed, because we already `await` the async call to `login()`.

Am I correct, or have I misunderstood how `expect.assertions` works?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`expect.assertions` is important when testing the error scenarios of asynchronous code, and is not redundant.

If you remove `expect.assertions` from your example you can't be confident that `login` did in fact throw the error.

```
it('calls the API and throws an error', async () => {
  try {
    await login('email', 'password');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.name).toEqual('Unauthorized');
    expect(error.status).toEqual(401);
  }
});
```

Let's say someone changes the behavior of `login` to throw an error based on some other logic, or someone has affected the mock for this test which no longer causes `login` to throw. **The assertions in the `catch` block won't run but the test will still pass.**

Using `expect.assertions` at the start of the test ensures that if the assertions inside the catch don't run, we get a failure.

Comment: So if the test code has something like `fail` after `login` in this case, `expect.assertions` is not needed?

Answer (score 18):

This is from Jest documentation:

> Expect.assertions(number) verifies that a certain number of assertions
>   are called during a test. This is often useful when testing
>   asynchronous code, in order to make sure that assertions in a callback
>   actually got called.

So to put in other words, expect.assertions **makes sure that the n number of assertions are made** by the end of the test.

It's good to use it especially when writing a new tests, so one can easily check that correct assertions are made during the test. Async tests often pass because the intended assertions were not made before the test-runner (Jest,Mocha etc.) thought the test was finished.

Comment: Indeed they can most certainly be removed, however i wouldn't do it at all, why the willing to run the risk that in the future a given change would not break the tests?

Answer (score 11):

I think we are missing the obvious here.

expect.assertions(3) is simply saying ...

I expected 3 expect statements to be called before the test times out. e.g.

```
expect(actual1).toEqual(expected1);
expect(actual2).toEqual(expected2);
expect(actual3).toEqual(expected3);
```

This timing out business is the reason to use expect.assertions. It would be silly to use it in a purely synchronous test. At least one of the expect statements would be found in a subscribe block (or other async block) within the spec file.

Comment: simplest explanation !!

Answer (score 4):

To ensure that the assertions in the catch block of an async/await test are adequately tested, `expect.assertions(n)` must be declared as shown in your code snippet. Such declaration is unnecessary for async/await tests without the catch block.

It seems quite unintuitive but it is simply the way it is. Perhaps, for certain reasons well deep within the javascript runtime, the test environment can detect when an await'ed' promise successfully resolved but cannot detect same for await'ed' promises that failed to resolve. The creators of the test environment would likely know verbatim why such is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that apart from error testing, I find it challenging to see a real use for `expect.assertions`. The above snippet can be changed to the following with the same guarantee but I think it reads more naturally and doesn't require me to count how many time I call `expect`. This is especially error-prone if a test if complex:

```
it('calls the API and throws an error', async () => {
  try {
    await login('email', 'password');
    fail('must throw')
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.name).toEqual('Unauthorized');
    expect(error.status).toEqual(401);
  }
});
```

Comment: What if the promise returned by `login()` takes a long time to reject? Due to slow connection, etc. Does your test pass or fail? The runtime doesn't find it's way to `fail()` for sure because of the `await` behind `login()`. no?

Answer (score 0):

its not redundant, its to insure that your async code actually ran and your test passed not just because your test runner is fast(actually its kind of a race condition here), however if you really want to remove `expect.assertions()`,  you can use `done` instead, by passing done as parameter and call it at the end of your test to insure its been called e.g

```
it('calls the API and throws an error', async (done) => {
  try {
    await login('email', 'password');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.name).toEqual('Unauthorized');
    expect(error.status).toEqual(401);
  }
done()
});
```

or you can use `return` to ensure that all your logic been done execution