# Is it considered good practice to use expect.assertions in tests with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I see an increasing number of projects using `expect.assertions` during tests written with Jest. Is doing this good practice? Should we do this? What is the real gain from doing this?

Comment: The only good use for this I know is to count assertions from callbacks (`then`, etc) that aren't guaranteed to be executed. Which in turn is XY problem because this code can be transformed to straightforward async..await.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50816254/3001761.